# develop image to text converstion application for mobile os

Tags: java, android, c++, c, api

I was thinking to develop an image to text conversion application for android.

Im looking if there is any existing api written in java or c/c++. Can anyone suggest me about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please search with the keyword OCR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Comment: thank you Mat, I didn't know the keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site might be helpful for you
[google OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/)
[sample code](http://code.google.com/p/mezzofanti/)